# How do I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors from jqXHR object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error when I try to use Ajax for an url (no surprising as I have no cross domain policy file in place yet.) What was surprising to me is how difficult getting the correct error message is. Here is my js:

```
$.ajax({
    url: e.target.href,
    dataType: 'html'
}).always(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("xhr.status: " + xhr.status);
    console.log("xhr.statusText: " + xhr.statusText);
    console.log("xhr.readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
    console.log("xhr.responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
    console.log("xhr.responseXML: " + xhr.responseXML);
    console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
    console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    console.log("xhr.redirect: " + xhr.redirect);
    $('#output').html(xhr.responseText);

});
```

And here is console log of the error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load {url}. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '{url}' is therefore not allowed access.
```

And here is the console log that I write, as you can see there is no mention of the correct error message.

```
xhr.status: 0 
xhr.statusText: error 
xhr.readyState: 0 
xhr.responseText:  
xhr.responseXML: undefined 
textStatus: error 
errorThrown:  
xhr.redirect: undefined
```

How can I get the correct error text?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amity84/hMupL/)

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the error objet and get a state :

```
error : function(e) {
     $('#output').append("state: " + e.state()); 
     $('#output').append("<br/>");
}
```

You should get 'reject'

Comment: Status "rejected" is not much better than the default message "error" is there really no way to get a better error message? And as a follow up, is "reject" always the same as "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present .." ?

Comment: I'm not sure you could get the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' variable because the response and response header is blocked in the browser runtime, the console log message is sent from it and thus never passed to javascript engine.